# compute the norm of a linear operator

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces

good morning everyone, 
I am preparing my functional analysis exam and I can't resolve this exercise:

Let $$ H = L^2([0, 3])$$ and let T : H → H be defined by

$$Tu(t) = (1 + t^2)u(t)$$

i) Prove that T is linear and continuous and compute its norm.

I find out that the norm of T is lower than 10 but I cannot show that It is greater or equal than 10 to conclude that it is actually equal to 10.
can anyone help me?

thank you in advance

Comment: HINT: Consider a sequence $f_n\in L^2(0,3)$ of continuous functions which has unit $L^2$ norm and that concentrates on $t=3$, where $1+t^2$ is maximal, as $n\to \infty$.

Comment: How did you get that $10$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos using Holder's inequality. 10 is the maximum of $$1+t^2$$ in [0,3]

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro thank you!

Comment: @whowho You don't need Holder. Just write down norm square of $Tu$ and pull out the maximum of $(1+t^{2})^{2}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $u_n(t)=\sqrt nI_{(3-\frac 1 n,3)}$. Then $\|u_n\|=1$ for all $n$. Now $\|Tu_n\|^{2}=n\int _{3-1/n} ^{3} (1+t^{2})^{2} \, dt \to 100$ so $\|T\| \geq 10$. As you have already noted the bound $(1+t^{2})^{2}  \leq 100$ gives the opposite inequality.

Comment: Thank you very much. The exercise also ask to show that T is compact. To do so, I am trying to show that it is weak-strong continuous, since L2 is reflexive, but I don't think it will work because I can't manage to demonstrate the strong convergence in L2. Do you suggest other ways?

Comment: @whowho $T$ is not compact. If $\{e_n\}$ is an orthonormal basis for $L^{2}[0,3]$ then it is easy to see (using the fact that $1+t^{2} \geq 1$)  that no subsequence of $\{Te_n\}$ is Cauchy in the norm.

Comment: again, thank you very much!